# Access Windows 10 directories through "/cygdrive/c". Cygdrive no longer exists

Tags: ssh, windows-10, mobaxterm

The SSH Server I am using is the MobaSSH (home) and the SSH Client is MobaXTerm.
I want to run a script from our CI/CD server, and set it up to run it over SSH.

Until recently this worked perfectly. I do this on both Windows 7 and Windows 10 machines. When I upgraded the Windows 7 Machine and reinstalled the MobaSSH, I could no longer access the "/cygdrive/c/*" directory.

Is there a way to somehow create this directory so that I can access it through that path again? Or edit the Path variable of the system to allow the path to be used again?

Also, if connect to the SSH Server through MobaXTerm, I can see that that path does exist?

[image]

But through bash or CMD its says the following:

[image]

The script I want to run is on the machine with the SSH installed. The script on the CI/CD server is as follows:

```
"/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe" "C:\Deployment\InjectIps.ps1" "${bamboo.IpAddress}" "${bamboo.IpAddress1}" "${bamboo.IpAddress2}"
```

There might be a better way to do this, running the script through SSH worked for me.

P.S This is a local network, I am aware this is not the most secure option.

Comment: If all your machines are running Windows 10, now might be a good time to consider migrating from Cygwin to WSL.